# Line–line intersection with two points given on each line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

According to the article [Line–line intersection on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection), if we describe line segments as:
$$ L1 = (x1, x2) + t(x2-x1, y2-y1) \\
L2 = (x3, x4) + u(x4-x3, y4-y3)
$$
then the value t/u for the interseption point on the L1 could be represented as:
$$
t = \frac
{\begin{vmatrix}
    x1-x3 & x3-x4 \\
    y1-y3 & y3-y4 \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}
    x1-x2 & x3-x4 \\
    y1-y2 & y3-y4 \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

$$
u = \frac
{\begin{vmatrix}
    x2-x1 & x1-x3 \\
    y2-y1 & y1-y3 \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}
    x1-x2 & x3-x4 \\
    y1-y2 & y3-y4 \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

Question 1. How did they get this representation of t?

Question 2. Can we use apply same approach for vectors of n-dimensions?
$$
L1 = v1 + t(v2-v1) \\
L2 = v3 + u(v4-v3) \\
$$

$$
t = \frac
{\begin{vmatrix}
    v3-v1 & v4-v3 
    \end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}
    v4-v3 & v3-v1
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$
$$
u = \frac
{\begin{vmatrix}
    v1-v2 & v3-v1
    \end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}
    v4-v3 & v3-v1
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

Comment: In more than two dimensions lines (not parallel) may not intersect.    Question 2 - this is the better way to represent the lines.  The symbolism needs some explanation.

Comment: $$\textbf{x}_1+t\textbf{v}_1 = \textbf{x}_2+u\textbf{v}_2$$ 
$$\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2 = -t\textbf{v}_1+u\textbf{v}_2$$ 
$$[-\textbf{v}_1;\textbf{v}_2]\textbf{y}=\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2$$
where $\textbf{y}=<t, u>$

Then,
$$\textbf{y} = inv([-\textbf{v}_1;\textbf{v}_2])(\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2)$$